# pandasgui: cannot import name 'sip' from 'PyQt5'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

I have installed in the `pandasgui` into my environment successfully using `conda install -c conda-forge pandasgui`. I am running into issue when I import it.

Mycode:

```
from pandasgui import show
```

Present output:

```
from pandasgui import show
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11980/4274761675.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandasgui import show

  File "C:\Users\..\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pandasgui.gui import show

  File "C:\Users\..\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\gui.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pandasgui.store import PandasGuiStore, PandasGuiDataFrameStore

  File "C:\Users\..\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\pandasgui\store.py", line 6, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, sip

ImportError: cannot import name 'sip' from 'PyQt5' (C:\Users\..\anaconda3\envs\..\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py)
```

Comment: The problem is caused by the version of PyQt5 that anaconda provides, if you use pip to install PyQt5 you will see that there is no such error.

Comment: @eyllanesc how about `conda install -c anaconda pyqt` instead of pip?

Comment: try execute: `conda install -c conda-forge pyqt5-sip`

Comment: @eyllanesc Looks like it worked but new error came up `AttributeError: 'QWebEngineSettings' object has no attribute 'ShowScrollBars'`

Comment: try execute: `conda install -c conda-forge pyqtwebengine`

Comment: also `conda install -c conda-forge pyqt5`

Comment: @eyllanesc I saw it installing many things and finally asking to delete a file manually. Should I do that? I don't know this going to do a boomerang? Your inputs: `Executing transaction: \ WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(143): Could not remove or rename C:\..\icudtl.dat.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(699): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::qt-5.12.9-h5909a2a_4'.
Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:..icudtl.dat'
()`

Comment: I am not an expert in anaconda but I always see that kind of problem, my recommendation: create a virtualenv and there install pandasgui using pip: `python -m pip install pandasgui` and do not use anaconda if it is not mandatory.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your inputs. pyqt5 did not go through and gave error `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pyqt5 `. Okay. I will try installing it in the new environment. Thanks